# How to run PHP code by remote interpreter in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I am slowly despairing with PhpStorm. I am trying to set it up so that I can run PHP files via the Run command and have it call /usr/bin/php on my remote machine via SSH.

Here is my server setup:

I have a system user called john who has his home directory in /home/john. Inside there is a directory called project that is a Git repository.
I have another FTP only user called doe who is locked in /var/www/doe. The files there are served by Apache under https://doe.server.com/. doe is also the owner of /var/www/doe

And here is my PhpStorm setup:

Remote PHP interpreter configured over SSH and recognized by PhpStorm. SSH credentials have john as user.
Deployment FTP server configured with root path / and under Mappings, the local path is mapped to / and the web path is also /. Account being used is doe.

When I edit files and upload them to the deployment server, everything works fine and I can view the changes in the browser accessing doe.server.com. However, when I attempt to run the PHP file, PhpStorm calls /usr/bin/php and passes the path to my local file which of course does not work, so there must be a problem with the mapping and I assume it's because I cannot find a spot to tell PhpStorm that the root is /var/www/doe.

Any ideas? Using SFTP wouldn't work because the SSH user john cannot write stuff into /var/www/doe. The FTP server is configured to create directories / files with doe:doe ownership and rwxr-xr-x / rw-r--r-- permissions.

Comment: Better configure correctly and use SFTP instead of FTP - definitely works this way (maybe even use SFTP entry when configuring remote PHP interpreter as well) -- it worked this way for me with no issues at all. Not sure why FTP does not work here .. but have seen similar threads/tickets with similar to your results.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not possible because the htdocs folder is accessible only by virtual FTP users. :(